# Does splitting 1 tempdb file into 4 require a SQL Server restart?

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, tempdb, logs, datafile, sql-server-core

please can anyone help?

I have a SQL 2008R2 instance with 4 cores, configured with 1 tempdb data file and 1 logfile.

I want to change this setup as per best practices by adding 3 additional euqally sized files. I want to size the files to fill the capacity of the drive. The dedicated drive has a capacity of 50GB but a recent ad hoc user query pushed the size up to 47GB (log is 2GB).

Are the following order of steps correct?
Will it require a restart of SQLServer?
Will the files be used proportinally by SQL Server correctly after, i.e. not pushing contention to a new file?

1) Shrink the original data file down to 12GB using DBCC SHRINKFILE. 
* Size taken up by the drive should now be 14GB (2GB log + 12GB data file 1)

2) Add 3 new additional data files at 12GB each. 
* The drive should now be full at 50GB capacity

This will be done during a planned outage on a production system, but wanted to know if there will be any potential issues with the approach?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Ignore my first post. I mis read the volume size of 500gb and not the actual of 50gb. No restart is required and the order looks fine. Expect some locking if your tempdb is heavy used

Comment: Is that query something the user is likely to do again?  Because a single query can only use a single tempdb file.

Comment: No, was a one off query. Autogrow will be disabled after the files have been sized for the drive, so it won't blow the disk.

Comment: @JonathanFite I've never heard that.  Certainly a Temp Table can be spread across all the files in a filegroup, as it's a normal table.  Is there some particular use of Tempdb space that you are thinking of?